# How to test CPU L1 and L2 cache specifically on arm

Tags: linux, arm, cpu-cache

Is there any tools/tests available to validate CPU L1 and L2 caches during bsp/bring up activities.

I am using memtest86+ on my ARM board, But not able to find much information on how to get cache misses and hits especially while writing data to L2.

Comment: This isn't clear, do you want to validate L1 and L2 cache in some piece of software you've implemented in a bsp? You want to count cache misses with respect to some software you've written? You can't "write data" to L2 cache in any instruction set, caches are internal by definition.

Comment: At the _board_ level, the caches just work (modulo silicon errata); there's nothing to "validate" there. The validation already happened when designing the CPU core, and further when integrating the SoC.

Comment: some designs allow direct access to caches as ram, but normally you work through them instead of on them.  A memory test that covers more than the amount of cache you have will at least exercise them once.  The more cycles through or the nature of the data, the better.  If you have a 256K cache and 1Gig of memory then do a memory test on that 1Gig, pseudo random data or choose your favorite memory test or tests.

Comment: Normally the L1 and L2 are inside the chip, certainly possible to have the L2 outside, but most likely inside, so design verification already happened. And the chip is tested either before packaging or after packaging and before shipping so there is nothing to test.  The primary purpose of board level testing is to test the solder joints and maybe the pcb, so you dont need to test the transistors inside the chips (including the ram) you do want to exercise the connections, low speed and high speed where possible.  L1/L2 normally doesnt fall into this category.

Comment: A simple pseudo random number test can cover the data andress and control pins for chip customers using the BSP to bring up their boards.  As far as their board bring up goes.  It is up to them to design a manufacturing test for their product not you (unless contracted to do so), you cant predict every possible product derived from your chip and write tests for it.  Not the purpose of a BSP anyway.

Comment: FWIW, a chip product I work on we do have direct access to the cache ram, was far easier to initialize the ECC syndromes than try to gyrate some code that completely covered these rams for the purpose of initializing them and then enabling ECC.  As the need for ECC/EDAC increases either ARM, etc are directly going to give us access, or the chip designers will need to give us direct access (or use the built in mbist or something) in order to initialize ram before enabling ECC monitoring.